# How to use a Column in a particular table as Table name from which i need to delete or insert or update my data

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

For suppose i have data like below

```
   Id        Table Name 
    1          T1
    2          T3 
    3          T2
    4          T1
```

can i write a single Query to delete ids of 1 and 4 from Table T1 and 2 from table T3 and 3 from table T3?

Comment: Short answer: No, each delete generally requires a separate query.  That aside, your current design might be sub optimal.  Why can't all these records be in the same table?

Comment: basically am trying to use oplogs of mongo db to update the dump of it on daily basis which will be on bigQuery, so designed tables for delete, update and insert in above way from all collections.

Comment: You will need dynamic SQL here, meaning you will need to write code which generates the delete SQL statements.

Comment: will this be your option? `SELECT ... INTO @delete_query; PREPARE stmt FROM @delete_query; EXECUTE stmt`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, thats an option i was thinking, but is there any way that we can build it using BigQuery was my search. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ProGu sorry didnt get you

Comment: Use `select` to construct a delete statement and store into a variable, then use `execute` command to run the delete statement

Comment: Since your requirement is now on dynamic SQL for BigQuery, I would suggest opening a new stackoverflow thread for the same.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Tim, your requirement of deleting from multiple tables is not possible in a single query rather, you can use dynamic SQL to generate each delete SQL statement and use the execute command to run the query.